# Overriding components in list

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to make a two-dimensional list to keep track of the rectangles in a board game I'm making.

I've made the function for the board and I was told to write the following for the second list to save the references:

```
rect = [[None for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(n+1)]

rect[i][j] = canvas.create_rectangle(i*height/n,j*width/n,(i+1)*height/n,(j+1)*width/n,width=1,fill='red',outline='green')
```

Can someone tell me how the indexes of the rectangles are being saved? When I `print rect`, nothing appears?

Comment: you're not looping over i and j, so you're only changing one of the rect values

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your list comprehension you create just a nested list full of `None` and then create one single rectangle for the last values of `i` and `j` *after* the list comprehension.

Instead, you should put the call to `create_rectangle` *inside* your list comprehension:

```
rect = [[canvas.create_rectangle(i * height / n, j * width / n, 
                                 (i+1) * height / n, (j+1) * width / n, 
                                 width=1, fill='red', outline='green')
         for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(n+1)]
```

This way, `rect` should contain the IDs of the several rectangles, which you can then use to modify those rectangles, e.g. for changing their color.